# Failed to re-publish a page - Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We are getting some strange error when re-publishing the same page. The page was published successfully the first time and we can see the page from presentation server. It failed with the following error (see below) when we tried to publish it again (no change to page). The page ran OK within template builder and we got the correct html output, it failed in the last committing deployment step (Prepare Transport, Transporting, Preparing Deployment and Deploying are all successful). Once it fails to publish the second time, it always fails to publish, and we can't un-publish it either. Also when we make a copy of the failed page and create a new page, we can publish the new page first time, the new page then fails to publush the second time with the same error.

Does anyone know what would cause this error?

Here is the error msg:

`Committing Deployment Failed Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-4210-66560, For input string: "", For input string: "", Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-4210-66560, For input string: "", For input string: ""`

Comment: Did you check the transport and deployer log files? Those might give a clearer error message, since this one seems fairly incomplete.

Comment: In addition it helps if you can give some more details about your Content Delivery architecture. What transport are you using (HTTP, FTP, etC)? What database are you using (if any)? And it may help if you show (the relevant parts of) your CD configuration files (transport and storage seem most likely).

Comment: Could there be some permissions weirdness on your delivery server where you can't overwrite an existing file?

Comment: Have you considered joining the Area 51 proposal for a Tridion dedicated website? http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you can publish successfully the first time and not on subsequent attempts (including unpublishes) might point to locking issues (of course, I'm speculating, but this would be consistent with your symptoms.

One thing that is known to cause file locking problems is anti-virus software. Usually it's recommended to exclude your site and data directories from coverage by anti-virus scanners.

Similarly, there can be locking issues for the deployed resources that are stored in a database. Is your database server giving errors or warnings? For example, are there issues with enlisting the resources in a transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple deployer ? sometime it happens due to multiple deployer configured and one of them not configured as it should. First time your page may be picked up by the right deployer and  afterward by wrong one.

As frank suggested, share the transport and deployer log files sothat i or someone else can assist you in right direction.